# How to grow iframe height to match content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm aware that this question has been asked a number of time on SO and have looked over many of the posts but none seem to be as restrictive. I may not be able to do anything about this but I want to ask.

I need the content within an iframe to grow and shrink with the content. The main problem that I see is that javascript cannot be used because the site providing the framed content will only provide an iframe tag with a link to its content. There is of course no guarantee that the site where the iframe is placed will allow javascript so I don't see that as an option.

Is there another alternative to an iframe that will allow me to import dynamically growing and shrinking content that doesn't rely on javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP on the server-side to retrieve the content and then include it within the page. You can strip out the meta-data, and adjust the CSS and HTML with Xpath if you need to.

If it's a completely different bit of content for which adjusting the CSS and HTML won't work, then an iframe does remain about the only solution. If you have access to a server with a GUI, you could load the page and store the height in a database, and then set the height of the iframe on load.

Comment: From what I can tell, he can only provide a piece of static HTML for the embedding site, that would be the iframe element.

Comment: Hmm, yes - can I clarify @Jim. There is site1.com providing content that you need to display on site2.com. Who's in charge of site2.com? Why can you not be certain that site2.com will allow JavaScript? Do you mean just that the user might not have JavaScript enabled? You have tagged with PHP, which made me think server-side was allowed.

Comment: Blowski, thanks. I may have store the height in the database as you suggest. I've already thought about that and honesty, I think it's my only option.

Comment: @jim It is possible to get the height automatically, but you will need access to a server with a GUI, plus it won't be 100% accurate unless you check on every browser.

Comment: Blowski, I provide the iframe link but nobody knows where that iframe will wind up. We certainly don't have control over it. Site2.com or site3, 4, 5... could be run by anyone. We just don't have control of where it's hosted

Comment: @jim Do you provide the entire iframe code - i.e. `<iframe src="site1.com" />`? If you do, then passing the height is an option. If you're just literally giving the src and you can't guarantee JavaScript, then no... this would be impossible as you have no means of changing the code. What's inside an iframe can't change what's outside of it, and the `iframe` tag itself is outside the iframe.

Comment: It's possible (though tricky) to automatically load the site on a server with, say, Windows or Ubuntu Desktop installed. You can then use JavaScript to calculate the rendered height of the element that you're trying to detect and then store that value in a database. Then when you pass the `<iframe>` tag to site2.com, you include `height="100"` (or whatever). Not an ideal solution but I don't know of another way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://kinsey.no/blog/index.php/2010/02/19/resizing-iframes-using-easyxdm/

I believe it still works.

Comment: Thanks Fareesh, going there now.

Comment: That one requires JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that with current technology and browsers, this just cannot be done. Not without JavaScript.

And it's not pretty even with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Matti, I'm starting to see that myself. Is there anything that I can use to export dynamic content off my site that will resize to that content without using scrollbars?

Comment: @jim: If I knew of any way that didn't involve server side programming or JavaScript, I would have mentioned it.